# PHP if else syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I hope that you guys help me with php mysql.

```
if ($video != NULL $photo != NULL ) { // checking id if foto id != 0 or video id != 0 show me 2 icon  
$icon = '<i class="fa fa-camera"></i> <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>' . "\n";  


}  
elseif ($video!= NULL) { // if video id != 0 show me only video icon  
$icon = '<i class="fa fa-camera"></i>' . "\n";  

}elseif ($photo!= NULL){ // photo id !=0 only show me photo icon  
$icon = '<i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>' . "\n";  
}  


else { echo '';  


}
```

I'm trying to get video or photo icon by id
if video_id or photo_id was 0 then no photo or no video. So no icon.
But if video_id or photo_id != 0 then icons should showing up

thanks in advance

Comment: `if ($video != NULL $photo != NULL )` that is wrong; it's missing an (logical) operator `AND/OR`. a.k.a. `&&/||`.

Comment: You dont need an if elseif for this if your outputting the same strings, just use ifs.

Comment: Voting this one as a mere typographical error.

Comment: @chris85 there isn't; anymore that is.

Comment: I have removed the mysql tag. This question has nothing to do with mysql, but I understand Stack Overflow often "suggests" tags based on frequency of association with the primary tag of the question.

Comment: @BillKarwin *aye aye!* - TItle still has mysql though, heh!

Comment: @chris85 oh brother....... they just added mysql now, *sigh*

Comment: Is there an issue with the `mysql`? If the question is just how to write an `if`/`elseif` then you should remove that. Keep the question as minimal as possible.

Comment: There is no any problem with mysql i think so. It is php syntax

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if ($video != NULL $photo != NULL )
```

with

```
if ($video != NULL && $photo != NULL )
```

Notice that you didn't add `&&` between the two variable checks.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as its the only correct answer. Guess they didn't look at whats being outputted..

Answer (score -1):

In your `if` conditional you no have `AND`, you need to do like this

```
if ($video != NULL && $photo != NULL )
```

The correct way..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone *Hmm....*, what if one fails though? The question IMHO is unclear but I already voted as a typo.

Comment: i used logical operator but icons was visible every line

Comment: OR would cause it to output both if one is true, which is not right.

Comment: Yes. exactly that's it what i am trying to do ... output both if video_id and photo_id are true. Or output video if video is true..

Comment: [Then use @GuillaumeHarari answer, dont forget to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819912/661872) ;p

Comment: Yes, the corect conditional is AND (&&) not OR (||), Sorry!!